# Enabling Migrations causes namespace to stop working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, entity-framework-migrations

I created a WCF / EF code first service.  I created a folder called "*Models*" and there created my /POCOs.  In there I created my context.  Now in the *Package Manager Console* I run `enable-migrations`.  This returns Success and adds the *Migrations* folder and */Configuration.cs*.  Now the problem shows itself.
The auto-generated code in *Configuration.cs* looks like this;

```
internal sealed class Configuration :
    DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyService.**Models**.MyContext> 
{
    public Configuration()
    {
         AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
}

protected override void Seed(MyService.**Models**.MyContext context)
```

Now under the word Models I get the red squiggle and the error message

> The type name Models does not exist in the type MyService.MyService.

I have tried everything including renaming the Namespace and the folder.  Anywhere the myContext file is placed will cause this error.
I've tried deleting all existence of the Entity Framework and starting over many times but still can't figure this one out! :/

```
 namespace MyService.Models>     
 {
     public class MyContext : DbContext
     {
         public DbSet<Chain> Chains { get; set; }
         public DbSet<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Show the namespace and class declarations for both. Is the context public?

Comment: @SteveGreene You had me scared there but sure enough the context and the POCOs are all public.